# Filtering an array of File List objects via jQuery $.grep

Tags: jquery, arrays, file, object, grep

I'm trying to filter an array of File objects via jQuery $.grep.
For this particular example, I'm trying to filter via the file name.

So here is what I have so far:

Step 1: Create an array of files:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(fileBuffers, e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
```

Step 2: using fileBuffers:

```
var arr = $.grep(fileBuffers, function (fileBuffers, value) { return (fileBuffers[value].name !== filename) });
```

So I'm trying to create a new array, arr, that contains an array of files, except the file that has filename.

So far this is not working for me.  What am I doing wrong?.

Comment: You need to learn how to use the built-in debugger in your browsers developer tools. These kinds of "why does this function not do what I think it should do" questions are easy to answer once you've set a breakpoint and look at what *actually* happens, as opposed to what you believe.

Comment: I appreciate the tip.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for `$.grep` is;

```
var arr = $.grep(fileBuffers, function (file, idx) { 
    return (file.name !== filename); 
});
```

**Note** that the first parameter of the callback is the element in filebuffers and the second parameter is that item's index in the filebuffers array.

[Link to `$.grep` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

Comment: The 'Link to Documentation' is broken.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: thank you for this posting but I'm still not getting the desired results.  For example,  if I select files named A, B, C, and if C is filename I should just get back an array with A and B, right?  I'm, still getting back all three files.

Comment: @SeegeDev is it possible your array `filebuffers` doesnt contain what you think it does?  I suggest using the development tools in your browser and putting a breakpoint within the grep function to see what you are actually comparing.

Comment: thanks for your help!  I had to do a .trim() because of a whitespace!  Works great now!

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer was correct! I had a whitespace that crept into filename, so I had to do a .trim().

So:

```
var arr = $.grep(fileBuffers, function (file, idx) {
                                 return (file.name !== filename.trim());  });
```